# r mapply vs "bad lapply"

Tags: r, vectorization, lapply, mapply

I think I've missed something simple here:
I have a list of data.frames, and a list of row numbers to select.
Something like this:

```
a <- data.frame(q = c(1,0,0,0), 
                w = c(1,1,0,0),
                e = c(1,1,1,0),
                r = c(1,1,1,1))
b <- a + 1
c <- a + 2
d <- a + 3

data <- list(a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d)

ind_a <- c(1, 2) 
ind_b <- c(1, 3)
ind_c <- c(1, 4)
ind_d <- c(2, 4)

train <- list(ind_a, ind_b, ind_c, ind_d)
```

now, I'd like to select the rows, and I thought that the proper form could be

```
test1 <- mapply(function(x,y) x[y, ], data, train)
```

but the only way I can make it work is

```
test2 <- lapply(1:4, function(x) data[[x]][train[[x]], ])
```

that seems like a fake for-loop to me...

Where I'm wrong???

Comment: Just to know: `purrr::map2(data, train, function(x, y) x[y, ])` works too

Comment: `purrr::map2(data, train, ~ .x[.y, ])` is a more purrr-y way or even `~.[.y, ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `mapply`, the default option is `SIMPLIFY = TRUE` and it simplifies it to an array when the dimensions are the same.  If we change it to `FALSE`, the output will be a `list`

```
mapply(function(x,y) x[y, ], data, train, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Or use the `Map` wrapper

```
Map(function(x, y) x[y, ], data, train)
```